# Project Reactor Using EmitterProcessor as an event bus

Tags: spring, spring-boot, events, project-reactor, axon

We were testing out how to use EmitterProcessor as an eventbus. Basically we want to indirectly let the Spring Controller know that something was successfully was done, we pass a unique key which is listened for in the spring controller (So if a different key comes in for a different method, we ignore it).

```
public class RequestVerifier {

    // constructor
    public RequestVerifier(EmitterProcessor<String> emitterProcessor) {
        this.emitterProcessor = emitterProcessor;
        // put this subscription here for testing purposes
        emitterProcessor.subscribe(value -> {
            System.out.println(value);
        });
    }

    public void runValue(RequestData data) {
        requestService.accept(data);
        FluxSink<String> sink = emitterProcessor.sink();
        sink.next("SOME-KEY");
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "flux-event-handler-event-bus-emitter")
    public EmitterProcessor<String> createEventBusEmitter(){
        EmitterProcessor<String> emitter = EmitterProcessor.create();
        return emitter;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the first message gets passed through to the `emitterProcessor.subscribe`. However when the second message is sent when `runValue` is called for the second time and onwards we get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spec. Rule 2.12 - Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)`. How do we allow the subscription to accept a constant stream of data?

Also if relevant, we are planning to use this inside an axon event handler and pass a message or key from the event handler to notify the waiting controller of the result to send back to the user.

**UPDATE**

Also tried the following, did not work though

```
    @Bean(name = "flux-event-handler-event-bus-emitter")
    public EmitterProcessor<String> createEventBusEmitter(){
        EmitterProcessor<String> emitter = EmitterProcessor.create();
        return emitter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "event-autoconnector")
    public Flux<String> returnFlux(EmitterProcessor<String> emitter){
        return emitter.publish().autoConnect();
    }
```

Comment: How is this being called from the controller? Can you provide a MRE for the issue? Is `runValue` called multiple times? You only need to create a sink once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my playground Reactive CQRS repo, I played with wrapping reactive API around Axon Framework app.

I think you may find what you are looking for in here https://github.com/stefanvozd/Reactive-CQRS, but be aware, its still work in progress and it lacks comments/documentation...

Depending on what you are trying to do with this stream here are few examples

1. [Example](https://github.com/stefanvozd/Reactive-CQRS/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/stefanvozd/cqrs/reactiveaxon/input/rest/WebFluxRest.java) of rest controller that sends a command and waits for projection to become materialized and returns this view to the user in a non-blocking manner. For this, you should use subscription queries
2. [Example](https://github.com/stefanvozd/Reactive-CQRS/blob/8295106170544b64dd815dca5b2cb3e584d6c44c/src/main/java/com/github/stefanvozd/cqrs/reactiveaxon/utils/ReactiveEventBus.java) of Reactive Event Bus stream that u can inject as a bean and attach to the event stream
3. [Example](https://github.com/stefanvozd/Reactive-CQRS/blob/06f8eba1d4a09acbec0c8d7dc73ffa94ab5ac20a/src/main/java/com/github/stefanvozd/cqrs/reactiveaxon/projection/reactive/AccountSummaryProjection.java) of reactive event handlers, that saves projections using reactive DB driver r2dbc and you have backpressure support if you use Axon Server.

Right now, these are all experimental examples and if you can provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish I could provide you some guidance

Comment: With your second example, if you wanted to subscribe to messages I need to autowire in `Flux<EventMessage>` correct? So that begs the question will I run into the same problem mentioned `Spec. Rule 2.12 - Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once`. Do you know how I should implement a subscription correctly to avoid that?

Comment: Correct, just autowire Flux<EventMessage> eventStream; be careful, there are multiple types of EventMessage, you are probably looking for DomainEventMessage...

This class was least tested (with one subscriber-only), and not used in example at all, but publish() should help you share this flux with multiple subscribers, please check the documentation of this method and autoConnect()

Comment: So I just tried out using `emitter.publish().autoConnect()` but still resulted in the `Spec. Rule 2.12 - Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)` error in the second run, I have updated the main answer with an updated configuration code.

Comment: just tested  `Flux<EventMessage> eventStream; //ReactiveEventBus` example with multiple subscribers, works fine and no errors... Try using `ReactiveEventBus` and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: Also, try reusing `FluxSink<String> sink = emitterProcessor.sink();` by defining it as a bean. On new data you are creating new sink and processor unsubscribes from the previous sink, which might be the cause of your issue